# $\frac{\partial }{\partial t}(f \circ \phi^{-1} \circ \phi \circ \gamma)(0)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(f \circ \psi^{-1} \circ\psi\circ \gamma)(0)$

Tags: manifolds, chain-rule

[image]
I feel like this result is in a way obvious, since we can just apply the chain rule several times:
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{dt}(f \circ \phi^{-1} \circ \phi \circ \gamma)(0)
&= D_{f\circ\phi^{-1}\circ \phi}(\gamma(0)) \cdot \gamma' (0) \newline
&= D_{f\circ(\phi^{-1}\circ \phi)}(p) \cdot \gamma' (0) \newline
&=D_f(\phi^{-1}(\phi(p))) \cdot D_{\phi^{-1} \circ {\phi}} (p) \cdot \gamma'(0) \newline
&= D_f(p) \cdot D_{id}(p) \cdot \gamma'(0)
\end{aligned}
where $D$ denotes the Jacobian of the respective function.
We can do the same for the expression $\frac{d}{dt}(f \circ \psi^{-1} \circ \psi \circ \gamma)(0)$ and derive the same result.

Is that really it? Did I use somewhere that $f$ is a real valued function? Did I use that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are charts (except for the fact that the expression is well defined since the respective inverse maps exist)?

Comment: It’s even simpler than that, no chain rulse necessary at all, since both are equal to $(f\circ \gamma)’(0)$. Is this really the question you intend to ask?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am asked to prove.

Comment: Really? Is your first paragraph word-for-word what you’re asked to prove? I find this hard to believe since this equality as you’ve written is completely trivial. There are some other phrasings of such questions which are not ‘trivial’, hence my questioning.

Comment: I added a picture of the exercise and realised that I need the partial deriative. Does that change anything?

Comment: well, you’r dealing with functions of one-variable so $\frac{d}{dt}$ is right. And yup, now I’m sure this is a rather silly exercise because the charts ‘cancel’ out in the composition when you restrict all the domains sufficiently, so you’re simply left with $(f\circ\gamma)’(0)$ in both cases (unless their goal is to explicitly get you to prove that $f\circ\gamma$ is smooth and hence this derivative exists… but I’m guessing you’re already proved such basic results before this).

Comment: your argument however, is flawed, because $D_f(p)$ has no meaning. You’re working at the level of manifolds, so ‘Jacobian matrices’ no longer make sense, and you need to be slightly more careful.

Comment: Thank you, I understand that my solution is wrong. However, I don't know how to do this exercise now. Can I basically just write that it is trivial since the charts cancel?

Comment: that’s what I’d do